# Using xib and storyboard in the same project

Tags: storyboard, xib

Can I use storyboard and xib in the same project? I have stumbled on to a bump in the road which is now requiring me to use storyboard. I am original using XIB to create my app.

Answer (score 0):

You sure can. They are just instantiated different ways. To setup a storyboard file you call:

```
UIViewController *myVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryBoardName" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myStoryboardViewController"];
```

To setup a XIB based view controller you call:

```
UIViewController *myVC = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myXIBFileName" bundle:nil];
```

In either case you would then proceed to add the view to the hierarchy as normal:

```
[self.view addSubView:myVC.view];
```